# Overriding toString methods?

Tags: java

Am I going about this the correct way? I generated the toString().

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
return "Auto [exampleOne=" + exampleOne + ", exampleTwo=" + exampleTwo + ", exampleThree=" + exampleThree ", getexampleOne()=" + getexampleOne() + ", getexampleTwo()=" + getexampleTwo() + ", getexampleThree()=" + getexampleThree() + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
}
```

Comment: Does it work the way you intended?

Comment: The syntax is correct.

Comment: You've done it correctly.  Does it convey the information you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this overrides the `toString()` method, which will be called when implicitly casting an object of this class to a `String`. What will be displayed depends on the `String` your function is returning.

Note that `@Override` is already helping you figure this out. It tells the compiler *"hey, I want to override a function, please check, if this is actually being done"* ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why)).

Answer (score 0):

`Java Specification` does not use `toString()` as a logic of smth. and does not strict it. So the developer is free to implement this method on his own. I think there are a couple of recommendations:

- it should be simple;
- it should be easy to calculate;
- it should not throw an exception;
- IDE is used it to should class' object in the debugger, so it's better to print the most important values here in one simple line.

I do not recommend to use this method as user's output string or smth. like that. You should create a separate method for the formatted output string.